# OpenSource Cycling Computer

Tags: open-source

I hope this is the right place to ask such a question. Is anyone aware of an active and open source community project to develop a computer (embedded system actually) to monitor parameters/build stats for bicycle? I searched a bit, but no luck.

Comment: Hi Andrea, can you share a bit about what parameters and stats you're looking for and what kind of connectivity. If it's not somehow connected it might get more attention on another site.

Comment: Yeah I knew this could a bit OT. Actually the two main links I have in mind are toGPS services and possibly to host computer/smartphone for data processing/visualization. Not a big deal. I'm just curious to know if someone is already working on such a thing. Of course an open platform web-ready would be great I believe. Like ride->shower->check stats on the sofa